# Highlight cell if the active cells (two or more rows) is in the same column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I know how to highlight cell with conditional formatting for single active row

```
=CELL("address")=CELL("address",C$5)
```

How to do this but with two or more rows (5, 7, 9, 11)

Comment: So to be clear, if rows #, #, and # are selected, you want each of those rows highlighted? (where "#" is any row number)

Comment: What should happen if I select a cell in e.g. row 5?

Comment: With this formula, if i select cell in row 5 so c5 for example, then cell in row 3 will change fill color this cell will be c3.. i want to if i select a cell in multiple row (example c11, or c13, or c21) to c3 change fill color.. on this site i saw how this formula works https://www.google.rs/amp/s/www.techrepublic.com/google-amp/blog/microsoft-office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-a-specific-cell-in-the-same-column-and-row-as-the-selected/

Answer (score 0):

Base your conditional formatting on the AND of three conditions.

```
=and(row()>=5, row()<=11, mod(row(), 2)=1)
```

More recent versions of Excel could use `isodd(row())` instead of `mod(row(), 2)=1`.

Comment: I dont quite understand your answer.. can you write full formula.. so my conditional formatting selection is C3:AM3 and rows that i want to be part of this are rows 5 to 27..all odd number rows..thanks

Comment: That is the complete formula. Are you having trouble changing the 11 to 27?

Comment: Formula doesn't work.. i will tell you my steps.. first i select c3:am3, then click conditional formatting, then new rule, then use a formula to determine which cell to format.. and there i deleted my previous formula and paste yours.. and when i select cells in rows 5 to 11 nothing is shanging on cells in row 3

Comment: I think I might now understand what you are attempting. You should probably use a worksheet_selectionchange.

Answer (score 0):

## Highlight Cells in Specified Row

- In Visual Basic Editor (**Alt+F11**) copy this code to the sheet
  window (double-click) of the worksheet where you want to run this
  code.
- Adjust the values (`cRng`, `cRange`, `cRow` `cColor`) in the constants section
  to fit your needs.

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const cRng As String = "C3:AM3"     ' Target Range
    Const cRange As String = "C5:AM27"  ' Source Range
    Const cRow As Long = 3              ' Target Row Number
    Const cColor As Long = 3            ' Color Index e.g. 3 is Red.

    Dim rng As Range  ' Intersect Range
    Dim i As Long     ' Rows Counter
    Dim k As Long     ' Areas Counter

    ' Create a reference to Intersect Range.
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range(cRange))

    ' Remove color in all cells of Target Range.
    Range(cRng).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        ' Loop through Areas of Intersect Range.
        For k = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
            ' Loop through rows of current Area of Intersect Range.
            For i = 1 To rng.Areas(k).Rows.Count
                ' In current Area of Intersect Range
                With rng.Areas(k)
                    ' Check if current row number of current area of Intersect
                    ' range is odd.
                    If .Rows(i).Row Mod 2 = 1 Then
                        ' Apply color to all cells in row cRow of Worksheet
                        ' whose columns are the same as those of Current Area
                        ' of Intersect Range.
                        Cells(cRow, .Column).Resize(, .Columns.Count) _
                            .Interior.ColorIndex = cColor
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End With
            Next ' Row of current Area of Intersect Range.
        Next ' Area of Intersect Range.
    End If

End Sub
```